# Meteor.isCordova and Server side

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app

I am running a Meteor app on both browsers and mobile phones. What I want to do is to update the `Accounts.urls.verifyEmail` accordingly, so the web app opens if the user registered from the web app, and the mobile app gets launched if the user registered from the mobile app.

This is how I am trying to :

```
  Accounts.urls.verifyEmail                   = function(token) {
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
      return 'lybe://email_verification/' + token;
    }
    else {
      return Meteor.absoluteUrl('email_verification/' + token);
    }
  };
```

However, even when registering from the mobile app, `Meteor.isCordova` returns `false`.

How can I differentiate on the server from Web and Mobile app? 
`Meteor.isCordova` seems to return `true` on the client side only.

Any suggestion is most welcome

Answer (score 2):

Accounts.urls.verifyEmail  is called from server then you cannot use Meteor.isCordova. I think you can checking in email_verification page if client is ios or android or browser and redirect to correct user.

Or you can modify Accounts package and sending client type (ios, android, browser..) when user register

Comment: I'll look into the plugins code. 

Otherwise, just to be sure that I understood correctly, your first suggestion is to trigger a web page, and to check from the web page if I should trigger the app or not, that is correct? That sounds like an acceptable and rather quick workaround, although the cleanest would be passing the argument as you suggested.

Comment: Yes, this is simplest way to do this. I also adaptive for user when them register with browser but active with ios and more..